# Returning a value in recursion

Tags: c, pointers, recursion

I'm new to stackoverflow so feel free to change or edit my question as necessary.

I have the following code that I'm trying to fix, it is essentially just a inorder tree traversal:

```
void *inorder_traversal(void *heapstart, uint32_t size, void *address) {
    struct node *head = (struct node* )heapstart;
    if (head->left_child == NULL) {
        if (condition1) {
            if (condition2) {
                address = head->address;
            }
        }
    } else {
        inorder_traversal(head->left_child, size, address);
        inorder_traversal(head->right_child, size, address);
    }
    return address;
}
```

I'm currently trying to return a `void *` that is stored inside one of the nodes I'm going through. This node must satisfy the condition1 `(size < pow(2, head->initial_size) && size > pow(2, (head->initial_size) - 1))` and condition2 `head->current_state == free`. I have removed these from the code for ease of reading.

My issue arises when I am trying to extract the address and return it. I have that `address = head->address`. However because `head` is changing whenever recursion occurs, `head->address` always points to the last nodes `head->address` and not `head->address` that fulfils my condition.

Essentially i'm asking if there is a way to break the traversal whenever the condition is satisfied and return the address that I have stored.

Someone suggested I wasn't returning the right value, however i'm not sure what is meant by that.

Please let me know if there is any confusion.

Comment: what is the purpose of `head->left_child == NULL` check?

Comment: I'm only interested in leaf nodes and the way i generate my tree is that ill always have both a `left_child` and `right_child` and they will be `NULL` when initialised. So checking if theres a `left_child` is enough for me to verify its a leaf node.

Comment: Those recursive dives still return something, you know. Perhaps you should retain that rather than just set it up to ignore it. I also see zero point in passing `address` in this function. You only use it as an assignment target and, being a value parameter, it is ultimately worthless, since that reaping is lost anyway once the function returns.

Comment: are u looking for **the first** in-order node that satisfies those conditions?

Comment: @WhozCraig Yep I agree, there was no reason to pass address, it was merely something left over from an old solution i tried. I tried to have `void* address;` uninitialised in my main. Then pass it into this function and instead of returning `void*` i would instead have `void`, I would access it in my main after it had been initialised in this function.

Comment: @tstanisl Yep, I am currently just looking for the leftmost leave node that satisfies the condition.

Comment: Yeah, that won't work. `address = ....` means *nothing* to the caller of this function (including when the caller is itself recursively), thus the reason why I said you need to do something with those recursive dives. Those return values too, and should be reaped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess that the problem might be caused by using a function parameter `address` that behaves like a local variable. Thus modifications of `address` are not visible with context of other recursive calls.

I suggest not using this argument. Just return the results when the first node satisfying the conditions is found.

```c
void *inorder_traversal(void *heapstart, uint32_t size)) {
    struct node *head = (struct node* )heapstart;
    if (head->left_child == NULL) {
        if (condition1) {
            if (condition2) {
                return head->address;
            }
        }
        // this branch is empty
        return NULL;
    }
    // try left child, if it fails then try the right one
    void *address = inorder_traversal(head->left_child, size);
    if (address) return address;
    return inorder_traversal(head->right_child, size);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, Ill see if i can make it work.

Comment: This solution with some tweaks was everything i needed to get it to work. Makes so much sense in hindsight. Thanks you!

Answer (score 0):

In-order traversal is supposed to (recursively) visit the nodes in the order: node's left sub-tree, the node itself, the node's right sub-tree.

It is not clear what OP's `inorder_traversal` function is supposed to return if none of the nodes satisfy the condition, so I will assume it should return `NULL`.

I have omitted the `address` parameter from my version of the `inorder_traversal` function below since it is not used.

```
void *inorder_traversal(void *heapstart, uint32_t size)
{
    struct node *head = heapstart;
    void *address;

    /* Deal with empty sub-tree. */
    if (head == NULL) {
        return NULL;
    }
    /* Check the left sub-tree for a suitable address. */
    address = inorder_traversal(head->left_child, size);
    if (address == NULL) {
        /* Check the head for a suitable address. */
        if (condition1) {
            if (condition2) {
                address = head->address;
            }
        }
    }
    if (address == NULL) {
        /* Check the right sub-tree for a suitable address. */
        address = inorder_traversal(head->right_child, size);
    }
    return address;
}
```